# Saving a Checkbox with SharedPreferences, java

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I need to save a checkbox value for a settings tab in my app in android studio to change the sensitivity but I cant figure out why my SharedPreferences are not working, I thought I would try covert the Check Box to a boolean but this doesn't seem to save my data.

code:

```
private CheckBox checkSens;
private boolean cbValue;
private static boolean finalSens;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    finalSens = LoadPrefs();

    checkSens = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkSens);
    checkSens.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            savePrefs("CheckBox", isChecked);
        }
    });

    checkSens = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkSens);
}

public static boolean getCheckSens() {
    return finalSens;
}

private boolean LoadPrefs()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    cbValue = sp.getBoolean("CheckBox", false);

    return cbValue;
}

private void savePrefs(String key, boolean value)
{
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("CheckBox", value);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use setOnCheckedChangeListenerinstead of setOnClickListener to get the checkbox value. Please refer the below code.

```
checkSens = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkSens);
checkSens .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompundButton button, boolean isChecked)
    {

       savePrefs("CheckBox", isChecked);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, I made the change however, it still does not save my preferences.